# use php to check javascript var value?

Tags: javascript, php, html

im a little new to php and html, what im trying to accomplish is to check if an html var is true or false, but i need to do it in php, what im trying to do is the HTML var = true, a php timer will run, and if it = false it will not, and not finding to much on how to go about this, most of what i find is setting an HTML var to a PHP $var

[Link to code](https://github.com/C0nw0nk/CoinHive/blob/master/html-example/index.html)

Comment: Use client side js to request server side php with var parameter.

Comment: HTML does not have variables

Comment: Do you mean a `javascript` variable with `HTML` variable? What have you tried so far? Please provide your code.

Comment: sorry about that its so easy for me to go between the two, but yes i meant javascript

Comment: Share you code snippets, it'll be easier for everyone to analyze

Comment: its allot but here it is

Comment: Anyway you can't check a JS variable using PHP directly. Server-side (php) and client-side (JS) codes are completely different things that run in two different places (like two different physical machines). You'll have to send the value you want to check from your front-end to your back-end.

Comment: so im gonna have to have the miner  post to a php when its running? and have it return yes?